# N-way ANOVA in MATLAB: Undefined function or variable “denommat”

Tags: matlab, anova

I'm trying to perform N-way ANOVA in MATLAB with further multiple comparisons.
I have some measurements of ERP component amplitude in 6 different conditions (2 'form' and 3 'type' - those are the factors under analysis) in 15 subjects, I set subject as random effect. Here is my code:

`[ps, tbl, stats] = anovan(amplitudes{1,1}(:,1), {typevector, formvector, sbjvector}, ... 'model', [1 2 3], ...
'random', 3 ... );`

... that works perfectly fine as long as I want two outputs(ps and tbl). When I try to get stats for multcompare function, I get this:

```
Undefined function or variable "denommat".

Error in anovan/makestats (line 419)
    stats.denom = denommat;

Error in anovan (line 330)    stats = makestats(stats);  % nested
function
```

Any ideas how to deal with it? Is it possible to generate stats manually? Or maybe there is an alternative way to perform post hoc comparisons using just the given table?